# F# wpf async command completion status

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, f#

I've been experimenting with async commands using F# Viewmodule. The problem is when I click the button, the command get executed, but afterwards the button stays disabled.

Xaml:

```
<Button Content="start async worker" Command="{Binding StartAsyncCommand}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
type MainViewModel() as me = 
  inherit ViewModelBase()
//...
member __.StartAsyncCommand = me.Factory.CommandAsync(fun _ -> async { return () } )
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @FoggyFinder, we determined that the issue was actually with the App.fs file:

```
open System
open FsXaml
open System.Windows

type MainWindow = XAML< "MainWindow.xaml">

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  Application().Run(MainWindow().Root)
```

Creating basically empty App.xaml and starting like this:

```
module main

open System
open FsXaml

type App = XAML<"App.xaml">

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    App().Root.Run()
```

fixed it. If anyone knows the explanation for this, don't hesitate to provide it.

Comment: if this is your code it should be ok and you should probably raise an issue [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.ViewModule/issues)

Comment: @Carsten probably yes. The interesting thing is that I used async commands with Viewmodule successfully in a `Interaction.Triggers/EventToCommand` context.

Comment: well you could try and test if the `CanExecuteChanged` event is fired after your code if you like - I had a quick glance at the code on github and it seems fine to me - that's why I wanted to know if this is the exact code that caused the issue.

Comment: btw: there is one possibility: the code grabs the sync-context from the current-context when the constructor of `FunCommand` (this is what gets constructed in the end) is called - so you have to make sure that you are in the UI context when you call the getter for `StartAsyncCommand`- that's why I would suggest to move the definition into a `let startCommand = me.Factory.CommandAsync(...` and just return this in side the member: `member __.StartAsyncCommand = startCommand` - it's not a good idea to recreate those all the time

Comment: thinking about it - this issue (recreating the commands) might cause the problem in the first place - depending on how WPF handles those (I have no clue - never tried something like this here) it might not correctly reset the events to the new commands all the time

Comment: @Carsten thank you for your suggestions, however it didn't help, as well as FoggyFinder 's sample within a new solution.

Comment: in this case wrap this simple example up and fill in a bug-report on github

Comment: You probably have to call the command's raise property change event. Hence, you need to force the data binding to update. This is supported on DelegateCommands.

Comment: His viewmodel needs to notify the MVVM framework that CanExecute needs to be reevaluated.

Comment: @Carsten updated the quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

The problem is that there is no SynchronizationContext in place when you construct your ViewModel layer, which means that the internal code that pushes things back to the UI context don't work properly.

You can work around this by adding the following at the beginning of your entry point, before you call `Application.Run()`:

```
if SynchronizationContext.Current = null then
    DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
    |> SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext
```

This will make sure the `Dispatcher` is created and a valid `SynchronizationContext` is installed, and will likely fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

I used asynchronous commands, but this problem never arose. I tried to reproduce your code - everything is working fine. Are you sure you gave complete code?

Try to run the code:
.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="start async worker" Command="{Binding StartAsyncCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
type MainViewModel() as me = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()    
    
    let count = me.Factory.Backing(<@ me.Count @>, 0)

    member __.StartAsyncCommand = me.Factory.CommandAsync(fun _ -> async { count.Value <- count.Value + 1 })
    member __.Count with get() = count.Value
```

About the differences between

```
let dosomething _ = async { return () }
member __.StartAsyncCommand = me.Factory.CommandAsync(dosomething)
```

and :

```
member __.StartAsyncCommand = me.Factory.CommandAsync(fun _ -> async { return () } )
```

look this answer:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26511092#26511092

Comment: still the same issue. I'm using vs2015 with all updates and newest versions of nuget packages. What could it be?

Comment: I'm using vs2012 and not the latest version of FSharp.ViewModule. Tomorrow I will try with the new version.

Answer (score 1):

The easy workaround is to use interaction triggers:

```
<Button>
    <ia:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ia:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <fsx:EventToCommand Command="{Binding StartAsyncCommand}" />
        </ia:EventTrigger>
    </ia:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary.